# SqlPackage.exe is throwing an error that's breaking my deployment script

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sqlpackage

What does this error message mean? error MSB3073?

```
1>D:\BuildAgent\work\db3238a9996f31f9\DeployToEnvironment.proj(165,3): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" ^
D:\BuildAgent\work\db3238a9996f31f9\DeployToEnvironment.proj(165,3): error MSB3073:                         /Action:Publish ^
```

Comment: Has the layout of the error message not come out correctly in your post?

Comment: error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe"

Comment: Looks like your error message has wrapped so it's difficult for me to read - "/Action:Publish" appears to be a parameter of SqlPackage.exe.  Perhaps post a few more lines of your error log, for context.